# XML parsing with sub nodes

Tags: iphone, ios4, nsxmlparser

I need some guidance about XML parsing. in my case I have to parse XML it looks like

```
-<food-drive>
−<coordinator cordid="4">
       <name>Luis Abarca</name>
       <teamname>A parents</teamname>
       <target>$3,500.00</target>
       <received>$0.00</received>
       −<image>
        alink
       </image>
−<teammember count="1">
   −<member memid="3">
      <membername>Rub</membername>
      <email>ssn@gmail.com</email>
      <phone>(323) 807-3920</phone>
   </member>
</teammember>
</coordinator>
−<coordinator cordid="9">
     <name>Jani</name>
     <teamname>Woori's LA Keeper</teamname>
     <target>$200.00</target>
     <received>$0.00</received>
     −<image>
          alink
     </image>
</coordinator>
−<coordinator cordid="11">
    <name>Jan</name>
    <teamname>Woori LA Keeper</teamname>
    <target>$200.00</target>
    <received>$0.00</received>
   −<image>
       alink
    </image>
</coordinator>
−<coordinator cordid="13">
   <name>Julio Torres</name>
   <teamname>Our Town El Sereno</teamname>
   <target>$1,000.00</target>
   <received>$0.00</received>
  −<image>
      alink
   </image>
</coordinator>
</food-drive>
```

Here , the tag [coordinator] is main tag and the tag [teammember] is inner tag but this tag appears rarely. Now I want to parse this xml and store the data. I am confuse how store the data because  [coordinator] tag may have more then one [teammember] tag !!! any suggestion ?

Comment: If those are people's actual names, email addresses and phone numbers, you shouldn't post them.  Replace with fake data before posting.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Keep a mutable array of the team members and one object which points at "current".

If you're using the built-in XML parser, you would in `didStartElement:` allocate and put a new team member into the array, and set the object to point at it.

This way subsequent entries related to team members would be able to address that object for populating the data.